# Choosing the most appropriate neural network type

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, hardware

I want to use deep learning to improve cache hit rate. Let me explain a few basic principles of the cache.

Each cache entry can have one of two different priorities. The priorities decide when that cache line is evicted(lower priority first). In general, a cache should aim to have a hit rate as high as possible.

Currently the priorities are assigned statically according to the traffic type. And all entries belonging to the same traffic type would have the same priority.

Based on experiments I have conducted, this is not the best algorithm for highest hit rate. Cache hit rate improves if the prioroties are set based on the access pattern.

For example, suppose address 100 belonging to traffic type A is accessed for a certain period of time, and then other addresses belonging to traffic type A are accessed, and 100 is accessed again. Due to the intervening accesses to other addresses between the 2 two periods of accesses to 100, the entry corresponding to 100 gets evicted and needs to be refetched again. However, if 100 was assigned a higher priority, it would not be evicted and cache hit rate would be higher.

This is a naive example just to give an idea of what the problem statement is. The actual traffic pattern is very complex and it is generally very hard to manually pick which addresses to give a high priority. I hope to achieve this with a deep learning network.

For the moment, we can assume that the access pattern is known before hand. The goal is to initially feed the access pattern to the deep learning network. And then when the accesses are actually made, the network assigns the most appropriate priorities to the incoming requests and this should improve the cache hit rate.

What kind of of a neural network best suites this requirement? For training the network, I don't have any cues except the cache hit rate - a hit rate higher than baseline indicates that the network is performing well.

I don't have much experience in neural networks. Any leads related to the class of neural networks that can solve such a problem and details related to how it will be trained are much appreciated.